# No instance of overloaded function toupper matches the argument list

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

I am trying to use `toupper` to convert first letter to uppercase in string but it keeps showing error code below:

> no instance of overloaded function"toupper"matches the argument list

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    string s("some string");

    if(s.begin() != s.end()){
        auto c = s.begin();
        c = toupper (c);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `c` is an iterator pointing to the first character, not a char. you need to dereference it first

Comment: `s.begin()` is not a character, it's an iterator that can be dereferenced into a character, so do `auto c = toupper(*s.begin());`

Comment: In addition to what is said already, note that here, you are modifyng `c`, not the string itself. You may use `s[0]=toupper(s[0]);`

Comment: Use `front` not `begin`, and as stated above, use a reference to change the string itself instead of the variable,  i.e. `auto& c = s.front();`

Comment: This is C++, please use `<string>` instead or `<cstring>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing the iterator with `*` operator will do the work:

```cpp
*c = toupper (*c);
```